# how to navigate in bs4 using html hierarchy

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

basically I made a code that prints out the hierarchy of a target tag as in

```
 html.body.div['root'].div.section['breadcrumbs'].div.script['application/ld+json']
```

*brackets contain the class name in cases where there are more than one div

and I want to use this output in another python doc to get the content of the target tag

I tried using the method 
soup.body.div……
but couldn't figure out how to specify the div I want with the class I have in the hierarchy

Is there any way to specify which div I am calling with the class I have  using bs4 or is there any other library that could help??

Comment: please write the code you tried to solve your problem

Comment: Why don't you use CSS selectors? The same you can achieve with bs4 `select()` or `select_one()` method: `soup.select_one('html body div.root div section.breadcrumbs div script[class="application/ld+json"]'`

Comment: I am sorry @GiacomoM it is my first question and I didn't know how it all works

Comment: @AndrejKesely i didn't know there was such a method , thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly to method to select elements from soup

1. find -soup.find('h1')
2. find_all - soup.find_all('h3')